# Adding data to an existing function dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, dhtml

I was wondering if we can add data to a function which is already defined in Javascript.

```
    var win;
    window.onload= function()
    {

        win = window.onbeforeunload;
        win = win.toString();

        var firstLetter = win.indexOf('{');


        win = win.substring(firstLetter + 1, win.length - 1);
        //Getting the data of the function [firstLetter = first occurrence of { ]

        win = win + 'alert("More Unload");';

        `/* Here, I want to rebind var win to the window.onbeforeunload event*/`
    }   

    window.onbeforeunload = function () 
    {
        alert("Unload function");
        alert("More Unload");
    }
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function using `new Function(yourCodeString)`.

However, this kind of code rewriting is extremely messy and if you need it you are doing something wrong for sure!

Comment: Ok. See I am writing a plugin that has an onbeforeunload function. I want to be sure that my onbeforeunload doesn't collide if there is one on the page where my plugin would be integrated.

Comment: At least firefox doesn't even show the message provided in onbeforeunload. And using `alert()` in that function sounds super-annoying since it will be *two* popups the user will have to click away.